# html form and successfully message

Tags: html, django, forms

hello i have a simple html form with select option choose.
I want after form submit the user get successfully message like this

```
<p>your request is complete</p>
```

in the position of html form.

and if user press refresh then `html form` come back in page.

here the code :

```
<form action="" method="POST">
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>
  <input class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" type="submit">
</form>
```

any idea ?I am stack now

I know this method `action="other.html"` but I want to work in the some html page without create other html page.

Comment: Are you using any server-side scripting language? PHP, for example?

Comment: @showdev I working django

Answer (score 1):

you need django messages to do that

## views.py

```
from django.contrib import messages

if form.is_valid:
   #validating form here
   messages.success("your request is complete") 
   #return redirect here
```

Comment: yes thank you I know that work for django forms,i use django framework but that form in my case is simple html

Answer (score 1):

```
from django.contrib import messages


if reuqest.method == 'POST':
    form = FormName(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        # Code here
        # sSuccess message
        messages.add_message(request,messages.SUCCESS,"your request is complete")
    else:
        # error message
        messages.add_message(request,messages.WARNING,"your request is incomplete")
```

Comment: that after  `if request.method == "POST" ` ?

Comment: i repeat i have a simple html form not django form

Comment: in that case, show the success/warning message after your validation process in the view